# Java entity manager does not load changes when I manually update row

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple service injected by guice. It uses Hibernate, EntityManager.

```
class BrillantPaulaServiceImpl implements BrillantPaulaService {
    @Inject
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Status EnqueueStatusCheck(Integer statusId) {
       Status status = em.find(Status.class, statusId);
       EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
       try {
          //..... do some work
       } finally {
           if (transaction.isActive()) {
               transaction.rollback();
           }
       }
    }
    return status;
}
```

When I manually update row from pgsql, the "Status status = em.find(Status.class, statusId);" does not view changes. It returns old entity. What is the possible issue?

Comment: I would guess either you have a hibernate 2nd level cache or the pgsql statement was not committed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `em.find(...)` does is that it first checks persistence context and because there is cached entity it returns it instead of getting it from database. Here is some quote from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object)):

> Find by primary key, using the specified properties. Search for an
>   entity of the specified class and primary key. If the entity instance
>   is contained in the persistence context, it is returned from there. If
>   a vendor-specific property or hint is not recognized, it is silently
>   ignored.

In the case that cache is used, JPA will get the entities from there. It will track changes to those entities only if they are modified via JPA. If you update the underlying data yourself, either directly or via some other external system, JPA will not be aware of those changes.